# Rycote Softies - good buy?

Tags: rycote, windscreens

Has anyone used these? I'm looking for wind protection I can use on audience reaction mics which can protect my mics on a windy day without me having to roll them off at 500 Hz because of wind.

Thanks in advance with any experience you guys might have.

Answer (score 2):

Myself, I really do not like softies at all, to be frank. It nicks way to much of the highs for my taste and makes the sound dull and lack-luster.

I would instead recommend Rycote's blimp-systems! These I'm very fond of. The combination of a really well working zeppelin cage, a very decent fur, a con-box to remove cable vibrations, and a truly kick-ass suspension-set makes my a VERY happy panda :-)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your application...but, overall, I'm with Christian on this one. We have two at work, and I only use them if I've run out of the blimp systems. The softie mount doesn't isolate as well as the lyre or band mounts, and the things are THICK! All blimp systems cut a bit of the high frequencies, but these cut a bit more. Don't get me wrong, it's tolerable in most applications...it's just my personal prejudice against them. ;)

Something else to keep in mind if you do use them, you may want to put the softie on before plugging in and powering the mic. The inner mesh is plastic and very snug...scrape noise central.

Answer (score 1):

I use them all the time and they're great! It depends on how strong the wind is, of course.

Comment: What's the strongest wind you have used them in? Do you know an MPH by chance?


Answer (score 1):

We have three and they can cope up to about 25 mph.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you hear any coloration to the sound when the softie is on?

Comment: There is a little, but it is not much more than any other form of wind protection. 

Answer (score 1):

To me the softie isn´t the best choice because it just covers a part of the mic´s body.
For better wind *and* rain protection use the s- Series Kit. This one´s ok.